# Can't assign elements to index in array

Tags: arduino-uno, c++

I'm trying to create an array of strings. I'm building each individual string by parsing a json file and getting the strings between '{'s and '}'s. However, for some reason, my array is only assigning one index with the string i want. This is my code:

```
  String day = "";
  String Combo[] = {"0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0"};
  int x = 2;
  int number = 0;

  /* Read data until either the connection is closed, or the idle timeout is reached. */ 
  unsigned long lastRead = millis();
  while (www.connected() && (millis() - lastRead < IDLE_TIMEOUT_MS)) {
    /* Reads one character at a time*/
    while (www.available()) {
      char sym = www.read();

      if (sym == '{') {
        x = 1;
      }
      if (x==1){
        if (!day.concat(sym)) {
          //Serial.println("concat() error!");
        }
      }
      if (x==1 && sym == '}'){
        x=0;
        Serial.println(number);
      }

      if ((number > 0) && (number < 9) && (x==0)) {
        Combo[number-1] = day;
        Serial.print(day);
        Combo[number-1] = day;

        Serial.println(F("-------------------------------------"));
        Serial.println(Combo[number-1]);


        Serial.println(F("-------------------------------------"));
        Serial.println(F("-------------------------------------"));
        day = "";
        number +=1;
        x = 2;
      } else if (number ==0 && x ==0){
        day = "";
        number +=1;
        x = 2;
      }
      lastRead = millis();

    }

  }
```

Which returns this:

```
{
    "firstString"
    }-------------------------------------

-------------------------------------
-------------------------------------
{
    "secondString"
    }-------------------------------------
{
    "secondString"
    }
-------------------------------------
-------------------------------------
{
    "thirdString"
    }-------------------------------------

-------------------------------------
-------------------------------------
{
    "fourthString"
    }-------------------------------------

-------------------------------------
-------------------------------------
{
    "fifthString"
    }-------------------------------------

-------------------------------------
-------------------------------------
{
    "sixthString"
    }-------------------------------------

-------------------------------------
-------------------------------------
{
    "seventhString"
    }-------------------------------------

-------------------------------------
-------------------------------------
{
    "eighthString"
    }-------------------------------------

-------------------------------------
-------------------------------------
{
    "secondString"
    }-------------------------------------
```

Based on this output I know that day is being constructed correctly but for some reason isn't assigned to an index in Combo (except "secondString")
Does anyone know what's going on?

Ideally Combo would equal: {"secondString", "thirdString", ... "eighthString"}

Comment: Any chance you could show us the JSON file you are trying to parse?

Comment: Perhaps you are out of memory?

Answer (score 1):

I'm trying to understand your code.

1. It looks like `x` is a state variable, with the following values:

   ```
   2 = "Looking for start brace (`{`)"
   1 = "Found! Now accumulating `day` until stop brace (`}`)"
   0 = "Finished!"
   ```

   If so, you may instead want to use the following:

   ```
   enum States { Looking, Adding, Done };

   // int x = 2;
   States state = Looking;

   // x = 1
   state = Adding;

   // if (x==1){
   if (state==Adding) {
   ```
2. If you follow the flow of code, when `number` is still `0` and `x` finally becomes `0`, you:

   - Print out `number` - the first line of your output;
   - You then miss the main `if` (`number` is *not* greater than `0`);
   - And enter the `else` (which is satisfied);
   - And then you immediately clear your hard-earned `day`.
3. The second time through, after `x` becomes `0` again, this time you:

   - Print out `number` - the second line of your ouptut;
   - You *do* enter the main `if`:

     - You assign `day` to `Combo[1]`
     - You print out only the first seven entries in the the array (you want `<=7`, not `<7`)

       - This should print out `0{?}000000` (I don't know what `day` should be).
       - The fact that it doesn't seems to imply that your `concat()` failed. Can you please change it to

         ```
         // day.concat(sym);
         if (!day.concat(sym)) {
             Serial.println("concat() error!");
         } // if
         ```
     - You then print out the row of dashes - and start a new line.
   - The third time through, it seems to work - you get your `{$ "first string" $}` (where `$` represents `\n` and/or `\r` - can you strip those out?)

     ```
           // if (x==1){
           //    day.concat(sym);
           if (x==1 && sym>=' '){ // Don't concat new line characters!
               day.concat(sym);
     ```
   - And the final few times `concat()` seems to have failed again.

The reason I say "`concat()` has failed" is that it looks like `day` is still `""` when it is assigned to `Combo`

#### Edit

You've changed the code so that the main if now does the following:

1. Assigns `day` to `Combo[number-1]`;
2. Prints out `day` - this seems to work;
3. Assigns `day` to `Combo[number-1]` ***again***;
4. Prints out a line of hyphens - this works;
5. Prints out `Combo[number-1]` - this does **NOT** seem to work;
6. Prints out two lines of hyphens - this works.

Since 5 is printing out nothing, it implies that 3 failed. This really does look like you're in a low-memory condition, and the system is failing to allocate memory from the heap.

You don't say what Arduino you're working on - note that most don't have much memory, and if you're already parsing a JSON file you've probably used a lot of it. You also don't say which version of the Arduino IDE you're using. There was a `String` bug in the earlier versions.

Rather than trying to use the String class (a renowned heap hogger), you should try to use normal `char` arrays and work the buffer management yourself.

Comment: Thx for the advice. For #2, I don't want the first day string to be saved so that's normal. I implemented #3 and it does seem that my concat fails often. Do you have any advice on fixing this?